# jq: mapping all values of an object

Tags: bash, jq

Say I have an object like so:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

I want to use `jq` to convert this to:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "innerkey": "value1"
  },
  "key2": {
    "innerkey": "value2"
  },
  "key3": {
    "innerkey": "value3"
  }
}
```

i.e. I want to apply a mapping to every value in the object, that converts `$value` to `{"innerkey": $value}`. How can I achieve this with `jq`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's literally called `map_values`. Use it like this

```
map_values({innerkey:.})
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PKfmo-D8Jf)

Comment: Hah, fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the fact that iterating over an object iterates its values. So you could update those values on the object.

```
.[] |= {innerkey:.}
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/arV_7YXzQr)